# I have error message connecting a monitor to my netbook

Tags: ati, display, hdmi, output

I want to connect my [Lenovo S205 Netbook](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/laptops/ideapad/s-series/s205) with a `1080p` monitor, however the only way to get it to work is by *Mirroring the Display*.

I would like to use the top display at `1080p`. My attempts ended either in an error message not allowing me to perform the change or in a shrinked display, which had been `1080p`, but smaller with a black border. *When connecting the monitor using a VGA cable everything works fine.*

I would love to solve this by using the AMD proprietary driver, but hope to get it solved in any way.

Thanks for the nice edit, Lucio. Been a bit tired. Here is the exact Error message I receive, when aligning the monitor next to the Laptop Monitor:
The selected configuration for displays could not be applied.
required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(3200, 1080), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1920, 1920).

I may also mention that if I align the monitor above the Laptop monitor it works, but I get a black border around it on the 1080p monitor.

I changed the xorg.conf file, which allowed me to use both displays as wished, however now I still have to solve the problem with the black border on the 1080p monitor. the amd catalyst driver didn't help.

Comment: 1. To clarify, you don't want to mirror the display, you want to expand your desktop across both monitors, right?
2. What's the *exact* error message?
3. When you use the VGA cable, you're able to run both screens at full resolution, 1080p?

Comment: 1. depends, as long as i can achieve 1080p, but preferably I want to use both monitors when I plug in the hdmi cable. 2. The error message is: The selected configuration for displays could not be applied. required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(3200, 1080), minimum=(320, 200), maximum=(1920, 1920). I may also mention that if I align the monitor above the Laptop monitor it works, but I get a black border around it on the 1080p monitor. 3.When plugging in a VGA cable I can run the Laptop monitor at 736p + the 1080p monitor aligned above it properly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmmm... It sounds a lot like you don't have the available video memory, or that's what the driver thinks, but an AMD should definitely be able to drive two 1080p displays. Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

nvm fixed it.

-

lol, just kidding. In order to use multiply desktops it is necessary to expand the virtual size of your xorg configuration file first. Open that file with:

```
sudo -s    
gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Search for "Section "Screen"" and change "Virtual   x y" to whatever you need while maintaining the given format.

If you are lucky everything works now, if you encounter black bars on one of your monitors and use amd proprietary drivers there might also be following solution:

Open your amd catalyst settings (search amd catalyst with Unity or do it the Hardcore way using the Terminal:

```
gksudo amdcccle
```

) Go to Display Manager on the left side and expand the menu. After that you select the framed Display, move to the Adjustments tab and crank the Scaling options all the way to OVERSCAN (it might not be in caps for you).

-

Well, anyway that is what worked for me. Maybe nvidia has similar option.